# jQuery selectors are ignoring the classes that are manipulated after the page loads

Tags: class, jquery-selectors, jquery

I have some buttons that when clicked, invoke jQuery to remove and replace their class. The jQuery.mouseover event that I want to call is ignoring the manipulated classes, and only obeying the classes from the page load.

Here's an example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jodi/7BTdt/3/)

Details below:

I have a row of buttons that, when rolled over invoke some jQuery to add a .highlighted class to objects elsewhere on the page:

Here's example HTML:

```
<ul id="portfolioLinks">
    <li class="activeButton kittens"><a class="kittens" href="#"></a></li>
    <li class="activeButton otters"><a class="otters" href="#"></a></li>
    <li class="depressed donkey"><a class="donkey" href="#"></a></li>
</ul>
```

and the corresponding jQuery code:

```
var selectedType = '.' + $(this).attr('class');


$("li.activeButton a").mouseenter(function() {

    var selectedType = '.' + $(this).attr('class');

    $("div.pageContent div" + selectedType).addClass('highlighted');

});     

$("#portfolioLinks a").mouseleave(function() {

    $("div.pageContent div").removeClass('highlighted');

});
```

This works fine on the static content from the page load, but when I click on a button I get 
jQuery to add a `.depressed` class to `$(this)` and give all the others `.activeButton`:

```
$("#portfolioLinks a").click(function() {


    $("#portfolioLinks li").addClass('activeButton').removeClass('depressed');

    $(this).parent().removeClass('activeButton').addClass('depressed');

//do some other stuff

});
```

However, it seems to completely ignore the altered classes, and continues highlighting the divs matching a button that lacks the `.activeButton` class.

I spent most of last night and this morning trying to figure this out. I've tried all manner of `.not`s, `:not`s and `if`s, and I'm now completely lost.

Any guidance would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) here instead, like this:

```
$("#portfolioLinks").delegate("li.activeButton a", {
   mouseenter: function() {
    var selectedType = '.' + $(this).attr('class');
    $("div.pageContent div" + selectedType).addClass('highlighted');
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    $("div.pageContent div").removeClass('highlighted');
  });
```

[Here's your fiddle updated with the above code, working](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/7BTdt/4/).

The issue is that when you do `$("li.activeButton a")` you're not binding anything to the *class*, you're binding events to the elements you found *with* the class **when it was run**...the *elements* now have event handlers bound. Any changes in the future are irrelevant, the handlers are bound.

With [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) and [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) however, the selector is checked *when the event happens*, so it *does* matter that the class changed.  As a bonus, it's also cheaper for many elements, since there's *one* set of handlers on `#portfolioLinks`.

---

If using jQuery older than 1.4.3, you'll need the non-map form, like this:

```
$("#portfolioLinks").delegate("li.activeButton a", "mouseenter", function() {
    var selectedType = '.' + $(this).attr('class');
    $("div.pageContent div" + selectedType).addClass('highlighted');
}).delegate("li.activeButton a", "mouseleave", function() {
    $("div.pageContent div").removeClass('highlighted');
});
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much for your help! I'd never come across .live() and .delegate() before. They look like the way to get things done!